# How do I constraint my widgets to the parent view and to one another to ensure they are aligned as a whole?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-appbarlayout

My widgets appear to be perfectly aligned in the DESIGN display of android studio, however when I run my app, its appearance differs on the emulator. Only the two pair of widgets (a pair consisting of a textview and edit text) are in alignment as seen on the emulator. The centre pair is out of alignment. I want all three of my edit text to be along the same line or same x axis. I want all three of my text view to also be along the same line or same x axis.

[image: activity_main.xml DESIGN]

The first edit text to the left, Systolic Edit Text, is constrained to the parent view on the left and to the top. To the bottom, it is constrained to the SET Button whilst to the right, it is constrained to the middle edit text, Diastolic Edit Text. The first text view, Systolic, is constrained to the parent view on the left and to the top whilst it is constrained below to the Systolic edit text, and to the right to the third text view, Pulse.

The middle edit text, Diastolic Edit Text, is constrained to the parent view to the left, to the right and to the top. The Diastolic edit text is constrained to the SET button towards the bottom. The middle text view, Diastolic, is constrained horizontally to the Systolic text view and Pulse text view. The Diastolic text view is constrained vertically to the parent view on the top and to the Diastolic edit text at the bottom.

The last edit text, Pulse Edit Text, is horizontally constrained to the parent view on the right and to the Diastolic Edit Text towards the left. The Pulse Edit Text is vertically constrained to the parent view at the top and to the button at the bottom. The Pulse text view is vertically constrained to the parent view at the top and to the Pulse Edit text at the bottom. The pulse text view is horizontally constrained to the parent view on the right and left.

[image: activity_main.xml EMULATOR]

I understand that chaining will allow alignment of all button widgets as a whole. However, can this replicated for text views and edit texts? If so, please assist.

This is the code if required:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnset"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/btnset"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvdia"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
       android:text="@string/diatext"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etdia"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvpulse"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvsys"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etdia"
       android:layout_width="61dp"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:ems="3"
       android:hint="@string/bpressure"
       android:importantForAutofill="no"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textColorHint="#757575"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnset"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.464" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etsys"
       android:layout_width="61dp"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
       android:ems="3"
       android:hint="@string/bpressure"
       android:importantForAutofill="no"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textColorHint="#757575"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnset"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/etdia"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvsys"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
       android:text="@string/systext"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etsys"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvpulse"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.653" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvpulse"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
       android:text="@string/pulsetext"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etpulse"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.804"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etpulse"
       android:layout_width="61dp"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
       android:ems="3"
       android:hint="@string/bpressure"
       android:importantForAutofill="no"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textColorHint="#757575"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnset"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.919"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etdia"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvstatus"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
       android:text="@string/result"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnset"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.058" />
</
```

Comment: Well there are several things. First of all, you left and right EditText have a top margin of 116dp, and your middle widget does not, this is your actual problem. Second of all, you should constrain your EditTexts to the Views above them, and NOT the parent. Generally, you should constraint the Views relative to eachother, and not to their parents. Third of all, your right-most text view has a fixed top margin of 48dp, and your right-most does not. Your button should point to "etdia" and "etdia" should point to "tvpulse" and "tvpulse" should point to parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/btnset"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etpulse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/diatext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvpulse"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvsys"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etdia"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="3"
        android:hint="@string/bpressure"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvdia"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvdia"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvdia" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etsys"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="3"
        android:hint="@string/bpressure"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvsys"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvsys"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvsys" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsys"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/systext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvpulse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="@string/pulsetext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etpulse"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="3"
        android:hint="@string/bpressure"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvpulse"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvpulse"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvpulse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnset" />
</
```